# Using OpenCV with np.floats

Tags: python, opencv

How come when using cv2.line() it accepts np.float32 type casting, but when using cv2.circle it keeps asking for an integer.

Is this simply true or am i doing something wrong?

Code:

```
elif attribute.tag == "LineTo":
            nextPoint = attribute.attrib
            img = cv2.line(img,(np.float32(startPoint["X"]), np.float32(startPoint["Y"])),(np.float32(nextPoint["X"]), np.float32(nextPoint["Y"])),(255,255,255),3)
            startPoint = nextPoint

        elif attribute.tag == "ArcTo":
            endPoint = attribute.attrib
            xDiff = np.float32(startPoint["X"]) - np.float32(endPoint["X2"])
            yDiff = np.float32(startPoint["Y"]) - np.float32(endPoint["Y2"])

            if xDiff > 0:
                xDiff = xDiff/2
                middlePoint = np.float32((np.float32(startPoint["X"]) + xDiff)), np.float32(startPoint["Y"])
                print(middlePoint)
                cv2.circle(img, middlePoint, int(abs(xDiff)), (255,255,255), 3)

            elif xDiff < 0:
                xDiff = xDiff/2
                middlePoint = np.float32((np.float32(startPoint["X"]) - xDiff)), np.float32(startPoint["Y"])
                print(middlePoint)
                cv2.circle(img, middlePoint, int(abs(xDiff)), (255,255,255), 3)

            elif yDiff > 0:
                yDiff = yDiff/2
                middlePoint = np.float32(startPoint["X"]), np.float32((np.float32(startPoint["Y"]) + yDiff))
                print(middlePoint)
                cv2.circle(img, middlePoint, int(abs(yDiff)), (255,255,255), 3)

            elif yDiff< 0:
                yDiff = yDiff/2
                middlePoint = np.float(startPoint["X"]), np.float((np.float32(startPoint["Y"]) - yDiff))
                print(middlePoint)
                cv2.circle(img, middlePoint, int(abs(yDiff)), (255,255,255), 3)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "beamer.1.py", line 144, in <module>
    startProjection()
  File "beamer.1.py", line 123, in startProjection
    cv2.circle(img, middlePoint, yDiff, (255,255,255), 3)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The centre of the circle must be given as a tuple of two integers. You pass two floats and are surprised it generates an error saying it expects integer but got float. I must be missing something here...

Comment: That is exactly it, but my problem is that when given floats to cv2.line it works but when given to cv2.circle it does not work. My question is, why this inconsitency? Is it just that, inconsistent, or am I the one really missing something. Because when it is just inconsistent, i can work around it. But I rather not because I need the decimals for accuracy.

Comment: Yes, OpenCV is just inconsistent between these two functions. It is "simply true." I'd guess that the inconsistency arises from performance being much higher with integers and not floats in the circle drawing case. Or perhaps the functions were just written by two different people at different times. Regardless, you can [check the source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b39cd06249213220e802bb64260727711d9fc98c/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp).

Comment: Also, sub-pixel accuracy is one thing for detection purposes, but for *drawing*, it's a non-issue. You can't draw things sub-pixel accurate. Even drawing a simple line at an angle has all sorts of different ways to do it: different aliasing algorithms, whether you require the line to be 4- or 8-connected, binary or blended, and so on. You should make your program either completely oblivious to this (i.e. if you need something at a specific radius...just use that directly with a distance function; don't rely on pixel pushing), or study the implementation to know precisely how they work.

Comment: There is a way to draw an antialised circle in OpenCV. In Python, I was able to create one keypoint (x,y,radius are all floats) and draw it. pt1= cv2.KeyPoint(x,y,radius)  frame=cv2.drawKeypoints(frame, [pt1], np.array([]), (0,200,0), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

Answer (score 2):

This question can be answered by simply looking at the documentation. `line` takes two points. `circle` takes a point and a radius. While the points can be given in terms of floats, opencv requires the radius to be `int`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it seems even though I am casting xDiff and yDiff to integers the error persists. So therefore the error is in the MiddlePoint, my question stands. I cannot cast the drawing points as np.floats in cv2.circle but can in cv2.line

Comment: @MickRemmerswaal When are you casting them as `int`? If you cast them as `int` before you divide by 2, that turns them into floats again.

Comment: `cv2.circle()` can be used with the `shift` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Because these method accept different parameters, look below:

Method line()

```
void cv::line (
    InputOutputArray img,
    Point pt1,
    Point pt2,
    const Scalar & color,
    int thickness = 1,
    int lineType = LINE_8,
    int shift = 0 
)
```

Method circle()

```
void cv::circle(
    InputOutputArray img,
    Point center,
    int radius,
    const Scalar &      color,
    int thickness = 1,
    int lineType = LINE_8,
    int shift = 0 
)
```

For your convenience, the following type aliases are defined:

```
typedef Point_<int> Point2i;
typedef Point2i Point;
typedef Point_<float> Point2f;
typedef Point_<double> Point2d;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am using python and python does not have an equivalant of cvPoint

Comment: @MickRemmerswaal no, OpenCV for Python does not use the C++ structs from OpenCV, but it *does* use the same underlying datatype (32/64-bit floats, 8/16-bit images, and so on). The containers are different, the data types inside the containers are the same.